# Stack deploy works but I can't access to web page

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm following the official docker documentation on [docker wevsite](https://docs.docker.com/) and I'm  blocked in the part "[services](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/#run-your-new-load-balanced-app)".
First problem appaired when I did ````docker init swarm`I goy the error`Error response from daemon: could not choose an IP address to advertise since this system has multiple addresses on different interfaces (10.0.2.15 on enp0s3 and 192.168.56.101 on enp0s8) - specify one with --advertise-addr`I tried with the`--advertise-addr``` and the two ip addresses and it doesn't work.

I'm working on virtual machine, that's why I have two addresses, the default one and the second to connect from host machine.

When I execute `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml getstartedlab` I have a success message returned but when calling the url I have a 404 error.

I did exactly same command lines and same configuration than documentation before the init swarm.

Any solution, any idea?

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should initialise your Swarm Mode cluster first before you deploy stacks. Since there are multiple NICs attached to the VM, use `--advertise-addr` flag i.e. `docker swarm init --advertise-addr=10.0.2.15` or `docker swarm init --advertise-addr=192.168.56.101`. This address is used to add worker or managers nodes to the cluster. The try to deploy services via stacks. They would work.

Comment: I did it but it doesn't works for me. I didn't solve the proble but I tried to manage containers with rancher and with kubernetes and it works well